# chain complexes and homotopy limits

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $\mathbf{Ch}$ be the category of unbounded chain complexes (with the standard model structure ). The differential increases the degree $d_{n}:M_{n}\rightarrow M_{n+1}$. Consider the full subcategory $\mathbf{A}$ of $\mathbf{Ch}$ such that $A\in\mathbf{A}$ iff $d_{-1}=0$.

$\mathbf{Question:}$ Is it true that any object $M\in \mathbf{Ch}$ is equivalent to homotopy limit of objects in $\mathbf{A}$ i.e. $$M\sim holim_{i}A_{i}$$

Thank you for any help or reference!

Comment: Yes, $M=holim_{i\leq 0} t_{\leq i}M$ wherethe $t_{\leq i}M$ are the obvious truncations of the canonical $t$-structure, which come equipped with natural maps $t_{\leq i-1}M\rightarrow t_{\leq i}M$.

Comment: Fernando, why $t_{<i}M$ are in $\mathbf{A}$? can you do the same thing if we replace $\mathbf{Ch}$ by differential graded algebras? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, they are not in A, but they are suspensions of objects in A, hence homotopy colimits of objects in A.

Comment: Ehem, here my argument breaks. I'm mixing homotopy limits and colimits, and that's not good. I think I made myself a mess, as usually when I think of cochain complexes rather than chain complexes.